# OpenCV with watson studio

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, ibm-watson, watson-studio

I am trying to use watson studio for detecting images taken from webcam. I use opencv to capture the video first and then read it frame by frame. Following is small part of the code to checck if video is getting captured.

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.isOpened()
```

This code returns True when I use it with python 2.7 locally but this does not work at all and returns False when I use it in the notebook for watson studio. I am not able to understand why this is happening

Comment: after using it locally did you close it using `cap.release()`?

Comment: Locally I was able to take pictures and then after a certain number of frames was captured I closed it using cap.release(). But the same code does not turn on the webcam on watson studio and does not take pictures

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible.
Given, cv2 would try to open/locate camera at the runtime attached to notebook and
not the user's camera who is browsing the notebook/url.

The cv2 running in runtimes have no way to talk to user's browser/camera.

Now when i say runtime, it can be spark service or Environment attached to the notebook.

I would suggest to capture images and then upload to COS to do further processing of those images using cv2 if thats the usecase.

Thanks,
Charles.